# I need to insert a slider in a blog page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a blog www.rajputanahomes.com, when someone clicks on a blog a page opens with details of the blog and pictures related to it.

Now what i am trying to do is when someone clicks on one picture the picture must pop up and the pop up must have next button so all the images on existing page can be seen. I am using CKeditor to upload content on the page.

Is there any way we can put code on each html page created dynamically so the above feature works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the many free lightbox plugins. One of the easiest to use is [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).